# SQL 2008 Change tracking and detecting Updated data

Tags: sql, versioning, data-warehouse

I plan to implement this in an SSIS project. Since I don't have enterprise version of SQL server 2008, I have to make use of other methods.

Another way is to use triggers, but I am trying to avoid to many triggers.

With change tracking I'm having difficulties detecting the correct operation. The operation is marked as "I" when it should be "U". What am I doing wrong?

Here is a small example code. pKey = 2 should be "U"

```
use master;
go

create database CT_Example;
go

use CT_Example;
go

alter database CT_Example
set change_tracking = on
(change_retention = 2 days, auto_cleanup = on);
go

create table Employee 
(
pKey int not null,
Name nvarchar(50) NULL,
CT bigint null,
constraint pk_pKey 
    primary key (pKey)
);
go

alter table Employee
enable change_tracking
with (track_columns_updated = off);
go

create table Staging 
(
pKey int not null,
Name nvarchar(50) NULL,
CT bigint null,
);
go

insert into Employee (pKey,Name)
values
(1,'Jhon'),
(2,'Phill'),
(3,'Jones'),
(4,'Tom');
go

update e set
    Name = 'Harry'
from
    Employee as e
where
    pKey = 2;
go

update a set
    a.CT = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
from
    Employee as a;

update e set
    Name = 'Gabriel'
from
    Employee as e
where
    pKey = 2;

insert into Employee (pKey,Name)
values
(5,'Sing'),
(6,'Emily'),
(7,'Jane'),
(8,'Sami');
go

Delete
from
    Employee
where
    pKey = 3;

declare @last_synchronization_version integer;
SET @last_synchronization_version = (select ct from Staging);


select 
    *
from
    Employee as a
    right outer join changetable (changes Employee, @last_synchronization_version) as c
        on a.pKey = c.pKey;
go

use master;
go

drop database CT_Example;
go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
declare @last_synchronization_version integer;
SET @last_synchronization_version = (select ct from Staging);
```

And Staging table is empty, also `@last_synchronization_version = NULL`. Also it should be declared as `bigint`.

Try to run this:

```
select 
    *
from
    Employee as a
    right outer join changetable (changes Employee, 3) as c
        on a.pKey = c.pKey;
go
```

And you will see the row with pKey=2  as U.

Or you can ask for "What was the last change operation for row pKey=2?" like this:

```
SELECT @last_synchronization_version = sys_change_version - 1 
       FROM changetable (VERSION Employee,([pKey]), (2)) y
SELECT sys_change_operation 
       FROM changetable (changes Employee,  @last_synchronization_version) x 
       WHERE x.pKey=2
```

You can see that there is no need to store last version change by every row, it is provided by SQL server.

[As per documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934145.aspx) `changetable (changes Employee, null)` should do following:

> If the value is NULL, all tracked changes are returned.

But perhaps not the latest version of the change but only the first version of all the available changes per row.

You can try this script to see, how change tracking works:

```
use master;
go

create database CT_Example;
go

use CT_Example;
go

alter database CT_Example
set change_tracking = on
(change_retention = 2 days, auto_cleanup = on);
go

create table Employee 
(
pKey int not null,
Name nvarchar(50) NULL,
CT bigint null,
constraint pk_pKey 
    primary key (pKey)
);
go

alter table Employee
enable change_tracking
with (track_columns_updated = off);
go


declare @last_synchronization_version bigint;

insert into Employee (pKey,Name)
values
(1,'Jhon'),
(2,'Phill'),
(3,'Jones'),
(4,'Tom');


SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
SET @last_synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()-1 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee, @last_synchronization_version) x

update e set
    Name = 'Harry'
from
    Employee as e
where
    pKey = 2;



SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
SET @last_synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()-1 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee, @last_synchronization_version) x


update e set
    Name = 'Gabriel'
from
    Employee as e
where
    pKey = 2;

SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
SET @last_synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()-1 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee, @last_synchronization_version) x


insert into Employee (pKey,Name)
values
(5,'Sing'),
(6,'Emily'),
(7,'Jane'),
(8,'Sami');

SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
SET @last_synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()-1 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee, @last_synchronization_version) x

Delete
from
    Employee
where
    pKey = 3;

SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
SET @last_synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()-1 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee,  @last_synchronization_version) x

SET @last_synchronization_version = @last_synchronization_version-1 
SELECT @last_synchronization_version 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee,  @last_synchronization_version) x

SET @last_synchronization_version = @last_synchronization_version-1 
SELECT @last_synchronization_version 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee,  @last_synchronization_version) x

SET @last_synchronization_version = @last_synchronization_version-1 
SELECT @last_synchronization_version 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee,  @last_synchronization_version) x

SET @last_synchronization_version = @last_synchronization_version-1 
SELECT @last_synchronization_version 
SELECT * FROM changetable (changes Employee,  @last_synchronization_version) x

use master;
go

drop database CT_Example;
go
```